# Weighted Cox Regression Model Summary Tables with gtsummary package

Tags: r, gtsummary

Gtsummary works perfectly with the regular cox (e.g. coxph) model to produce high quality publication ready tables.

Is there a way to/does it also work with extensions to the Cox model e.g. weighted cox regression e.g. (from coxphw) package?

Sincerely,

nelly

```r
library(coxphw)
#> Loading required package: survival
library(gtsummary)



data("biofeedback")


# Weighted Cox Regression
fit <- coxphw(Surv(thdur,success) ~ bfb + log2heal, data = biofeedback, template = "AHR")

#summary(fit)

tbl_regression(fit)
#> coxphw(formula = Surv(thdur, success) ~ bfb + log2heal, data = biofeedback, 
#>     template = "AHR")
#> 
#> Model fitted by weighted estimation (AHR template) 
#> 
#>                coef  se(coef) exp(coef) lower 0.95 upper 0.95         z
#> bfb       0.5500412 0.3626904 1.7333244  0.8514462   3.528600  1.516558
#> log2heal -0.4086158 0.3503903 0.6645695  0.3344165   1.320666 -1.166173
#>                  p
#> bfb      0.1293782
#> log2heal 0.2435443
#> 
#> Wald Chi-square = 3.820731 on 2  df  p = 0.1480263  n = 33
#> 
#> Covariance-Matrix:
#>                  bfb    log2heal
#> bfb      0.131544337 0.005519103
#> log2heal 0.005519103 0.122773336
#> 
#> Generalized concordance probability:
#>          concordance prob. lower 0.95 upper 0.95
#> bfb                 0.6341     0.4599     0.7792
#> log2heal            0.3992     0.2506     0.5691
#> coxphw(formula = Surv(thdur, success) ~ bfb + log2heal, data = biofeedback, 
#>     template = "AHR")
#> 
#> Model fitted by weighted estimation (AHR template) 
#> 
#>                coef  se(coef) exp(coef) lower 0.95 upper 0.95         z
#> bfb       0.5500412 0.3626904 1.7333244  0.8514462   3.528600  1.516558
#> log2heal -0.4086158 0.3503903 0.6645695  0.3344165   1.320666 -1.166173
#>                  p
#> bfb      0.1293782
#> log2heal 0.2435443
#> 
#> Wald Chi-square = 3.820731 on 2  df  p = 0.1480263  n = 33
#> 
#> Covariance-Matrix:
#>                  bfb    log2heal
#> bfb      0.131544337 0.005519103
#> log2heal 0.005519103 0.122773336
#> 
#> Generalized concordance probability:
#>          concordance prob. lower 0.95 upper 0.95
#> bfb                 0.6341     0.4599     0.7792
#> log2heal            0.3992     0.2506     0.5691
#> x There was an error calling `tidy_fun()`. Most likely, this is because
#>   the function supplied in `tidy_fun=` was misspelled, does not exist,
#>   is not compatible with your object, or was missing necessary arguments (e.g.
#>   `conf.level=` or `conf.int=`). See error message below.
#> Error: Error in if (s$used.robust) {: argument is of length zero


# Weighted Cox Regression including interaction
fit2 <- coxphw(Surv(thdur,success) ~ bfb + log2heal + log(thdur):log2heal, data = biofeedback, template = "AHR")

#summary(fit2)

tbl_regression(fit2)
#> coxphw(formula = Surv(thdur, success) ~ bfb + log2heal + log(thdur):log2heal, 
#>     data = biofeedback, template = "AHR")
#> 
#> Model fitted by weighted estimation (AHR template) 
#> 
#>                           coef  se(coef) exp(coef) lower 0.95 upper 0.95
#> bfb                  0.6182977 0.3775157 1.8557663  0.8854853   3.889244
#> log2heal             0.9161724 0.5695166 2.4997043  0.8186820   7.632416
#> log(thdur):log2heal -0.5014355 0.3174131 0.6056606  0.3251223   1.128267
#>                             z         p
#> bfb                  1.637807 0.1014620
#> log2heal             1.608684 0.1076854
#> log(thdur):log2heal -1.579756 0.1141626
#> 
#> Wald Chi-square = 4.960668 on 3  df  p = 0.1747  n = 33
#> 
#> Covariance-Matrix:
#>                             bfb   log2heal log(thdur):log2heal
#> bfb                  0.14251810  0.0135771         -0.01358277
#> log2heal             0.01357710  0.3243492         -0.17034764
#> log(thdur):log2heal -0.01358277 -0.1703476          0.10075110
#> 
#> Generalized concordance probability:
#>                     concordance prob. lower 0.95 upper 0.95
#> bfb                            0.6498     0.4696     0.7955
#> log2heal                       0.7143     0.4502     0.8842
#> log(thdur):log2heal            0.3772     0.2454     0.5301
#> coxphw(formula = Surv(thdur, success) ~ bfb + log2heal + log(thdur):log2heal, 
#>     data = biofeedback, template = "AHR")
#> 
#> Model fitted by weighted estimation (AHR template) 
#> 
#>                           coef  se(coef) exp(coef) lower 0.95 upper 0.95
#> bfb                  0.6182977 0.3775157 1.8557663  0.8854853   3.889244
#> log2heal             0.9161724 0.5695166 2.4997043  0.8186820   7.632416
#> log(thdur):log2heal -0.5014355 0.3174131 0.6056606  0.3251223   1.128267
#>                             z         p
#> bfb                  1.637807 0.1014620
#> log2heal             1.608684 0.1076854
#> log(thdur):log2heal -1.579756 0.1141626
#> 
#> Wald Chi-square = 4.960668 on 3  df  p = 0.1747  n = 33
#> 
#> Covariance-Matrix:
#>                             bfb   log2heal log(thdur):log2heal
#> bfb                  0.14251810  0.0135771         -0.01358277
#> log2heal             0.01357710  0.3243492         -0.17034764
#> log(thdur):log2heal -0.01358277 -0.1703476          0.10075110
#> 
#> Generalized concordance probability:
#>                     concordance prob. lower 0.95 upper 0.95
#> bfb                            0.6498     0.4696     0.7955
#> log2heal                       0.7143     0.4502     0.8842
#> log(thdur):log2heal            0.3772     0.2454     0.5301
#> x There was an error calling `tidy_fun()`. Most likely, this is because
#>   the function supplied in `tidy_fun=` was misspelled, does not exist,
#>   is not compatible with your object, or was missing necessary arguments (e.g.
#>   `conf.level=` or `conf.int=`). See error message below.
#> Error: Error in if (s$used.robust) {: argument is of length zero
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: If there is no existing tidier in broom, you'll either need to write your own or check out the parameters package. You can use the model output and convert it to the broom tidy format. https://easystats.github.io/parameters/articles/model_parameters.html

Comment: ok, thanks Daniel, that is a bit advanced for me for now. I aim to get more advanced to do this someday. Copy and paste it is for now.